# When I attempt to deploy on GitHub all I can see is the Readme file

Tags: github

I am trying to deploy my project on GitHub, and every time it's either a 404 error when I switch it to `Docs/`, or it only shows the `README` file.

I am uploading it on the GitHub website.

How can I see my site content?

Comment: You should include a bit more details, how are you uploading it? (How exactly are you doing it on the website?) What are you trying to upload. If you get `404 Error`, the folder `Docs` does not exist. Either you deleted it, so you have to create it. Or, you are looking in the wrong repository. Furthermore, are you committing to the master branch?

Comment: What does **deploy my project on GitHub** mean. Edit your question to clearly state what you have, the problem, and your objective.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your [**Publication sources**](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site) for your GitHub Pages.

- select the main branch
- select the docs folder

[image: https://docs.github.com/assets/cb-72858/images/help/pages/publishing-source-folder-drop-down.png]

Then you won't have to "switch" to `docs/` when visiting `http(s)://<username>.github.io` (for a user site) or `http(s)://<username>.github.io/<repository>` for a project site, depending on the name of your GitHub repository (`<username>.github.io` or just `<repository>`)